# com.ilkgunel.hastaneotomasyonu.entity.Patients cannot be cast to com.ilkgunel.hastaneotomasyonu.entity.Patients

Tags: jsf, exception, casting

I am writing a JSF project with JPA and Spring Security. I am getting this error time to time,not all time. I researched and learned that this error occurs because of diferent class loaders. But I did not do any thing to do different class loaders. Does anyone know the solution of this exception?
My projects codes is here: http://github.com/ilkgunel/HospitalAutomationWithJavaEE

-Stack Trace

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ilkgunel.hastaneotomasyonu.entity.Patients cannot be cast to com.ilkgunel.hastaneotomasyonu.entity.Patients
at com.ilkgunel.hastaneotomasyonu.controller.GetPatientInformation.fillList(GetPatientInformation.java:65)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:147)
at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:813)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:343)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:260)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at com.ilkgunel.hastaneotomasyonu.filter.TurkishCharacterFilter.doFilter(TurkishCharacterFilter.java:22)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: This class is duplicated in the runtime classpath and loaded by different classloaders. In other words, the build is broken (it has placed the same class/library in multiple different places) and/or runtime classpath is dirty (you have manually placed the class/library in an external place also covererd by the runtime classpath). A concrete answer is hard to give as you didn't give away any detail about the build system and the runtime classpath. This is at least not a JSF related problem.

Comment: How can I fix the runtime classpath? Can you give me a few advises?

Comment: Does not anyone know info about solution? I need help to solve this bad and annoying error.

Comment: A concrete answer is hard to give as you didn't give away any detail about the build system (IDE, build system, build scripts, etc) and the runtime classpath (IDE, execution environment, target server, etc).

Comment: Well,I run this project on three IDEs. NetBeans,Eclipse and IntelliJ Idea to see is the program giving this error again. I run this project on GlassFish Server and Apache Tomcat to see is the program giving this error again. All of them error again repeats. On the other hand that is a maven project. Project firstly opened and run in NetBeans IDE and GlassFish Server. I don't know any info about build system, execution environment,build scripts, etc but if you tell me how can I learn them,I will tell you needed info to solve this error.
REGARDS

Comment: One example of "build system" is "Maven". It's responsible for building the project and producing the WAR (or EAR) file.

Comment: Thanks for this info. I have got a WAR file. Is duplication (error) in this file?

Comment: The `/WEB-INF/classes` and `/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar` folders covers the webapp's runtime classpath. It should contain absolutely no duplicates in classes nor contain JRE/JDK/server-specific libraries. Other folders covered by the webapp's runtime classpath are among others the `/lib` folder of the JRE/JDK/server themselves.

Comment: I examined my WEB-INF/classes folder and WEB-INF/lib folder. I could not not found any duplication. In entity folder there are classes that have got '_' end of class name. Does this cause the error?